# predictions with qlickview

Tags: analytics, qlikview

I am here to ask some small information regarding qlickview function and whether qlickview has some option regarding the prediction function or not

My Requirements:

I have some sales data from 2013 and 2014 and I want to predict the sales for 2015 what functions I can use to predict this specific data in qlickview ?

And not only sales but I have similar data for production and training for specific location and machine so if this works successfully for sales I can implement the predictions for other departments too

As there are lot of techniques and methods related to predictions I want to know which technique I need to apply in qlickview and how ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, there are a lot of techniques and methods and you would have to combine them in QlikView as there's no one function that can do it for you. I would look into time series modelling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series)

There's a good 3 part video tutorial on Youtube about time series modelling (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHdYEZA50KE&feature=youtu.be). Although it is done in Excel, you can apply the same techniques in QlikView.

You would probably have to use linear regression. QlikView provides some analytical functions which you can use to calculate the slope and the y-intercept of a linear regression (`linest_m` and `linest_b`).

All in all I have found QlikView not to be very good at calculating such things. For example, if you find that instead of linear regression, polynomial regression fits your data better then you would have to implement a lot of it by yourself. Maybe it would be wise to use some statistical programming language (e.g. R, Octave) and present the results in QlikView.

Comment: Thank you for your information Indrek, qlikview is quiet flexible tool for analysis and predictions but we need to give little efforts to understand the function as you said. I want to use some external data connections from SAP and one more thing is I want to suggest a software tool that the people can further use in the company too. So most of the people who are working in our company are non technical it would be better to prefer a tool which can update automatically from the main database

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that QlikView is quite flexible. You can certainly automate the process with QV Distribution service and have the end users use their web browser to connect to QV Access Point and view the results. Regarding prediction/forecasting, the following link might be helpful https://community.qlik.com/thread/5027

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot open the qlikview file but I will try to find some solution which fits for my problem. As per my view the expression builder works better then what I expected,even I am surprised that this good business intelligence and analytics tools don't have a fixed functions for predictions I hope they can develop some specific templates for forecasting which is on demand template now for lot of companies

Comment: You're probably using QlikView Personal Edition. That's why you cannot open the attached QV file. As for prediciton/forecasting functions, it would be great if there were an out of the box solution. But I guess each prediction/forecasting problem is slightly different, so it would be difficult to create a generalized solution.

Comment: Ya exactly slight difference exists but most probably with the data input but as most of the companies are transforming their data to SAP and if SAP offers Predictions mechanism along with SAP BI that would yield a good profit too or else the existing BI tools creates a effective dashboards in relation with SAP that makes all the difference. But for now I need to concentrate on project template :) Thank you Indrek for your help